# Skew a line on canvas using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am drawing lines on a canvas. The user can select a particular line and be able to skew that line. By *skew*, I mean they can drag one end point of the line to a desired point on the same x-axis. How can I do this using JavaScript and HTML5 canvas?

Comment: If you haven’t actually tried writing any code in JavaScript to attempt this yet, I think the answer you’re likely to get here is: Try writing some code to do it, and when you get stuck or run into a specific problem, then come back and show your code and ask a specific question.

Comment: I would like to help you with this, but your question is a little vague :)

Answer (score 0):

The general way to draw a line is this:

```
ctx.moveTo(line.startX, line.startY);
ctx.lineTo(line.endX, line.endY);
ctx.stroke();
```

and then you can add EventListeners and check to see if the mouse is near the line...

```
window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e)
{
    mouse.x = e.layerX || e.offsetX;
    mouse.y = e.layerY || e.offsetY;
    // check to see if the mouse is near the line(s) here...
    // you can change to x/y and start/end
    // example:
    if (mouse.x <= line.startX + 5 || mouse.x >= line.startX - 5)
    {
        // mouse is within 5px of first x
    }
});
```